# Is there a clear equivalent of 'show keyspaces' in cqlsh 2?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

What cqlsh command can I use to quickly see the keyspaces in a cluster? cqlsh does not provide `show keyspaces` and `describe cluster` isn't as concise as I want.

I'm working using the following specifications:

> cqlsh 2.2.0, Cassandra 1.1.10, CQL spec 2.0.0, Thrift protocol 19.33.0

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Very simple. Just enter this command in your cqlsh shell and enjoy

```
 select * from system.schema_keyspaces;
```

In C*3.x, we can simply use

```
 describe keyspaces
```

Comment: Found that instruction listed at the bottom of this: http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/dml/using_cql

Comment: The system.schema_keyspaces table seem to have been removed from c* 3.x series

Answer (score 47):

Just try this:

```
describe keyspaces
```

*However you may* need specs of approximately the following (rather than [those mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16612463/977087) by yourself [Crowie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/977087))

> [cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.0.6 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0]

Answer (score 13):

```
cqlsh> select * from system_schema.keyspaces;

 keyspace_name      | durable_writes | replication
--------------------+----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        system_auth |           True | {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1'}
      system_schema |           True |                             {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.LocalStrategy'}
 system_distributed |           True | {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '3'}
             system |           True |                             {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.LocalStrategy'}
      system_traces |           True | {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '2'}
```

Comment: **Note**:

This works with `Cassandra 3.0`. You can verify your version using the following query:

`SELECT release_version from system.local;`

Refer: [Querying from system.schema_keyspaces generates code=2200](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/151415)

Answer (score 4):

The correct way with C* 3.x series is:

```
List<KeyspaceMetadata> keyspaces = Cluster.getMetadata().getKeyspaces()
```

Then use `getName()` on the KeyspaceMetadata instances.

Comment: Hey Bsb. I think this answer relates only to when you want to get this information in Java. Is that correct? My question aims to be focussed on cqlsh console queries.  Apologies if I seem a bit off... obviously asked this question years ago and not using C* myself now. Asking so that I may improve your answer with edit or perhaps upvote and improve other answers the m