# How to list all the available keyspaces in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-cli

I am newbie in Cassandra and trying to implement one toy application using Cassandra. I had created one keyspace and few column families in my Cassandra DB but I forgot the name of my cluster.

I am trying to find if there is any query which can list down all the available keyspaces.

Anybody knows such a query or command?

Comment: [C* 3.x](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/134185/migration-from-cassandra-2-x-to-3-x-schema-keyspaces-table-is-gone-how-do-you) : SELECT * FROM system_schema.keyspaces;

Comment: This answer is outdated. Correct answer is in here [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612463/is-there-a-clear-equivalent-of-show-keyspaces-in-cqlsh-2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a clear equivalent of 'show keyspaces' in cqlsh 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612463/is-there-a-clear-equivalent-of-show-keyspaces-in-cqlsh-2)

Comment: C* 2.x: `SELECT * FROM system.schema_keyspaces;`

Answer (score 106, accepted):

If you want to do this outside of the `cqlsh` tool you can query the `schema_keyspaces` table in the `system` keyspace. There's also a table called `schema_columnfamilies` which contains information about all tables.

The `DESCRIBE` and `SHOW` commands only work in `cqlsh` and `cassandra-cli`.

Comment: Too much detail sometimes takes away simplicity,  Marco answer is on point.

Comment: `show keyspaces` in `sqlsh` in Cassandra 4.0 it raises an error ("Improper show command.") I used `describe keyspaces` instead.

Comment: did you mean SELECT * FROM system_schema.keyspaces? instead of SELECT * FROM system.schema.keyspaces? Please edit your answer...

Answer (score 454):

[cqlsh 4.1.0 | Cassandra 2.0.4 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0]

Currently, the command to use is:

```
DESC[RIBE] keyspaces;
```

Comment: Accept this as answer! And by the way, the output would print multiple keyspace names in one line.

Comment: Cassandra also allow a short-hand command as in:
DESC keyspaces

Answer (score 54):

Its very simple. Just give the below command for listing all keyspaces.

Cqlsh> Describe keyspaces;

If you want to check the keyspace in the system schema using the SQL query

below is the command.

```
SELECT * FROM system_schema.keyspaces;
```

Hope this will answer your question...

You can go through the explanation on understanding and creating the keyspaces from below resources.

**Documentation:**

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/create_keyspace_r.html
https://www.i2tutorials.com/cassandra-tutorial/cassandra-create-keyspace/

Comment: DESCRIBE does not work on latest cqlsh. This works

Answer (score 13):

Found it...`show keyspaces` command lists down all the keyspaces. I think earlier when I tried this command, I forgot to give last 's' in 'keyspaces'

Comment: You can use tab completion to see hints about how to complete a cassandra-cli or cqlsh command. That may be helpful to you if you forget the syntax. For example, just type "show " and then tab to see the valid show commands.

Comment: The secondary point in your answer is going to be (for some people) the most valuable part of the answer.  Things work a lot differently between "cqlsh" and "cassandra-cli" (and the question poster does not indicate which he is using).

show keyspaces;
describe (keyspace name).
    NOTE: If one is using "cqlsh", it requires quotes around any mixed or upper case names in a keyspace or columnfamily  (OK, the poster didn't ask this but it's a common user error if new to C*)

Comment: In `sqlsh` in Cassandra 4.0 it raises an error ("Improper show command.") I used `describe keyspaces` instead.

Answer (score 10):

To see all the keyspaces on your Apache Cassandra NoSQL Database Server use the command:

```
> DESCRIBE KEYSPACES
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Short and directly to the point.

Answer (score 8):

Once logged in to cqlsh or cassandra-cli.
run below commands

- On cqlsh

`desc keyspaces;`

or

`describe keyspaces;`

or

`select * from system_schema.keyspaces;`

- On cassandra-cli

`show keyspaces;`

Answer (score 5):

The `DESCRIBE` command is your friend. You can describe one keyspace, list keyspaces, one table or list all tables in keyspace, the cluster and much more. 
You can get the full idea by typing

`HELP DESCRIBE` in cqlsh.

> Connected to mscluster at 127.0.0.1:9042. [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.8
>   | CQL spec 3.4.2 | Native protocol v4] Use HELP for help.
>
> cqlsh> HELP DESCRIBE
>
> ```
>     DESCRIBE [cqlsh only]
>
>     (DESC may be used as a shorthand.)
>
>       Outputs information about the connected Cassandra cluster, or about
>       the data objects stored in the cluster. Use in one of the following ways:...<omitted for brevity>
> ```

- DESCRIBE `<your key space name>` - describes the command used to create keyspace

> cqlsh> DESCRIBE testkeyspace;
>
> CREATE KEYSPACE testkeyspace WITH
>   replication = {'class':'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '3'} 
>   AND durable_writes = true;

- DESCRIBE keyspaces -  lists all keyspaces

> cqlsh> DESCRIBE KEYSPACES
>
> system_schema  system              testkeyspace  system_auth
>   system_distributed  system_traces

- DESCRIBE TABLES - List all tables in current keyspace

> cqlsh:system> DESCRIBE TABLES;
>
> available_ranges          peers               paxos
>   range_xfers batches                   compaction_history  batchlog
>   local       "IndexInfo"               sstable_activity
>   size_estimates  hints       views_builds_in_progress  peer_events
>   built_views

- DESCRIBE `your table name` or DESCRIBE TABLE `your table name` - Gives the table details

cqlsh:system> DESCRIBE TABLE batchlog

> CREATE TABLE system.batchlog (
>       id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
>       data blob,
>       version int,
>       written_at timestamp ) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
>       AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
>       AND comment = '*DEPRECATED* batchlog entries' ....omitted for brevity

Answer (score 5):

1. login to cqlsh
2. use below command to get names/list of keyspaces present

   ```
        SELECT keyspace_name FROM system_schema.keyspaces;
   ```

Comment: it depends on the version of Cassandra... Also, how this answer is different from previous?

Answer (score 4):

DESC KEYSPACES will do the job.

Also, If you want to describe schema of a particular keyspace you can use

DESC

Answer (score 4):

To List all the available keyspaces in cassandra using cqlsh in CLI mode.

> Command : DESCRIBE keyspaces;

Example :

```
cqlsh> DESCRIBE keyspaces;
```

[image: Example1]

Answer (score 4):

**Defining A KeySpace**

Understanding A Database:-In Cassandra, A  database is defined as a Keyspace, Within the KeySpace Table Can be Defined.

**Checking ALL KeySpace**

```
cqlsh> DESCRIBE KEYSPACEs;
```

**Defining A Available Keyspace**

```
cqlsh> DESCRIBE KEYSPACE stack ;
```

Answer (score 2):

1. login to cqlsh
2. desc keyspaces;
3. select * from system_schema.keyspaces ;

Answer (score 1):

desc keyspaces will do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

DESCRIBE keyspaces to list all keysapces
DESCRIBE keyspace
https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_reference/cqlsh_commands/cqlshDescribeKeyspace.html

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a combination of `grep` and `awk`:

```
root@DC1-Node1:/home# nodetool tablestats | grep "Keyspace :" | awk -F ":" '{print $2}'
 system_traces
 system
 system_distributed
 system_schema
 device_tool
 system_tool
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but simplest way to see keyspaces is to use "DESCRIBE  keyspace" command. No need to grep and awk.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from above method, if you have opscenter installed,

1. Go to data tab > there you will see all keyspcaces created by you and some system keyspaces.
2. You can see all tables under individual keyspaces and also replicator factor for keyspace.

for more details check below link.
https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/6.1/opsc/online_help/opscDataModelingManagingKeyspace_t.html

Answer (score -1):

describes and desc command will give list of keyspaces in the cluster.Please find below output for more details.

```
cqlsh> describe keyspaces
reaper_db      system_auth  system_distributed
system_schema  system       system_traces
```

OR

```
cqlsh> desc keyspaces
reaper_db      system_auth  system_distributed
system_schema  system       system_traces
```

Comment: how is your answer is different from other answers? Also - these commands are only working in `cqlsh`, not everywhere...

Comment: cassandra@node1:~$ nodetool tablestats | grep "Keyspace :"
                                                                                                              
Keyspace : reaper_db
Keyspace : system_traces
Keyspace : system
Keyspace : system_distributed
Keyspace : system_schema
Keyspace : system_auth
cassandra@node1:~$

Comment: There are at least 4 answers that list the same commands for cqlsh