# Best way to test/validate a database connection when using Astyanax

Tags: dropwizard, astyanax

I'd like to add a database connection health check to my `Dropwizard` project but I'm not sure how to test if the database connection is valid with `astyanax`.

I have two ideas:

1. There's a `keyspace.connected()` function that I haven't been able to find
2. Create my own `connected()` function that attempts to send a query to test the connection and catches any connection exceptions.

Comment: I've made a quick check about [astyanax](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax). The most suitable thing to do (IMO) is to query the information schema for the keyspace you are interested in (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712967/how-to-list-all-the-available-keyspaces-in-cassandra)) - you will know if you can access the cluster and if the cluster knows about the keyspace you are interested in.

Comment: Also you can add/implement custom [ConnectionPoolMonitor](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/blob/master/astyanax-core/src/main/java/com/netflix/astyanax/connectionpool/ConnectionPoolMonitor.java) that could be integrated with the Metrics library used by Dropwizard. So you will have the internal connection pool stats directly together with the other stats on the default page.

Comment: Have you checked my comments?