# Keyspace system_auth does not exist?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I wanted to do the following command:

```
alter KEYSPACE system_auth 
WITH replication =  
       { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 
         'replication_factor' : 2 };
```

Is it normal that system_auth is not shown as a keyspace?

Basically the following error occurs:

```
Bad Request: Unknown keyspace system_auth
```

Also, how do I even view the keyspaces that exist? Is viewing them even possible in cqlsh?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612463/is-there-a-clear-equivalent-of-show-keyspaces-in-cqlsh-2

Answer (score 5):

That keyspase is not created when you use `authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator`
 (which is by default). So, setup your `authenticator`, restart your node, and you'll be fine

Comment: I am using ccm and do what you indicate but still the system_auth keyspace is not available

Answer (score 0):

The system_auth keyspace does not exist in a fresh cassandra installation . This will automatically be created when authentication is enable by changing the two properties in cassandra.yaml i.e. "authenticator:  PasswordAuthenticator" and "authorizer: CassandraAuthorizer" .

To view the keyspaces use the cql command "desc keyspaces" or "select * from system.schema_keyspaces;".